# Using sudoers to run a script without a password

Tags: linux, bash, sudoers

I'm trying to run a script that automatically adjusts my screen backlight, which requires it to run elevated.

As such, I tried adding it to my sudoers file so I can run it without a script.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to make it work.

The file is located at /usr/local/bin/backlight.sh

Any tips?  I'm kinda new to this part of Linux...

/etc/sudoers:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
username ALL=( root ) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/backlight.sh
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: You're right.  My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt your user is "username".  Change your line and replace "username" by your actual user.

Ex. my user is nic.  sudoers would then be:

`nic ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/backlight.sh`